# Can Warp in yesod used to host CGI application?

Tags: yesod, warp

An old python CGI application is now running under ocsigen with cgimod extension. Whether or not warp support CGI application just by some configuration ?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You can certainly use Yesod with the `wai-handler-fastcgi` or `wai-handler-scgi` libraries to make a CGI application using Yesod. Is that your question?

Comment: sorry ! i am a yesod newbie. I will have a look at wai-handler-fastcgi

Comment: Now i am using mighttpd2 which runs CGI very well

Comment: z_axis: Could you write an answer and accept it saying you used mighttpd2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am using mighttpd2 which runs CGI very well.

Regards!